# Any VCS that implemented to see section's change history?

Tags: git, version-control

Are there any Version Control Software (VCS) that implemented to see section's change history?

For example, I guess there are a VCS repository named *foo*. And it has some history about file creation and changes.

**List of files of *foo* repo**:

```
main.c
```

**History**:

```
998ecf8 Current
d41d8cd Change the message
98f00b2 Change to K&R styles
04e9800 Initial commit
```

**998ecf8 *Current*: `main.c` (Omitted below)**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

**d41d8cd *Change the message***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hi, world!");
}
```

**98f00b2 *Change to K&R styles***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

**04e9800 *Initial commit***:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("Hello, world!");
}
```

Now, I'll get all change history of a section `Hi, world`, in `main.c`.

```
$ vcs find 'Hi, world'
"Hi, world" was first added at 98f00b2->d41d8cd:4.

 #include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
-    puts("Hello, world!");
+    puts("Hi, world!");
 }

"Hi, world" was removed at d41d8cd:4->998ecf8.

 #include <stdio.h>
-int main()
-{
+int main() {
-    puts("Hi, world!");
+    puts("Hello, world!");
 }
```

It's possible with cache? If yes, Which VCS does support the feature? If not, What algorithms does need to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log` has options to cover just about anything you might mean by this.  There's `-L`, that tracks a range of lines by pattern or by (starting) line range, `-G` that looks for changes that affect a particular pattern, and `-S` that looks for commits that change how many times a string occurs.

Comment: Thank you. It works quite simply. But How can I see the diff?

Comment: Oh, I see. Append `-p` option to see diff, `-i` option to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's achievable by using git and a little shell-fu. Build a script, first you could get the list of commit hashes of the occurrences of your search term during your repository history by using:

```
git  rev-list --all | xargs git grep "Hi, World"
```

Remember that you should place you search term in a regex pattern, then build a function for iterating upon those hashes and use this to display the changes for the immediate ancestor:

`git diff COMMIT^ COMMIT`

Append those results in the output and make the necessary adjustments for your desired format.